# devops - how to automate provisioning a feature from the WSO2 p2 repository?

Tags: wso2

The wso2 [release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) shows that all the features available for the Turing release are available in a [p2 repository](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/).

The [p2 overview page](http://wso2.com/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2) describes using the GUI for provisioning a feature.  However, in the world of devops and continuous delivery it is preferable to automate system setup.

Eclipse has a [p2 director application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Director_application) for scripting eclipse provisioning.

**Question 1**: Is it possible to automate the setup of Carbon Core Turning and a feature?

**Question 2**: If so, how?

Comment: I have posted this question to stackoverflow rather than the dev@wso2.org mailing list as I believe this question will be of interest to users who may not think to visit the dev mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make the feature installation repeatable is to use the carbon-p2-plugin. Look in the pom.xml file of any WSO2 product (under the module/p2-profile-gen section)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about automating it. However, there are two ways that come in to my mind.

1) Normally you can do it without the management console as WSO2 server can be started with OSGI console. You can start the server

> sh wso2server.sh  -DosgiConsole

Then you can use p2 Provisioning Commands to install feature..

2) All management console functions have been exposed via web services. Therefore this feature management UI is also calling BE web services of WSO2 Carbon server. You can use these BE web services and can be automated them.  WSDL can be found [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.stub/4.2.0/src/main/resources/)